# Create bootstrap-modal from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have the following code (which is the HTML from the example):

```
var modal=
        '<div class="modal fade" id="infoModal"'+id+'tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">'
        +'<div class="modal-dialog">'
        +'<div class="modal-content">'
        +'<div class="modal-header">'
        +'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'
        +'<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<div class="modal-body">'
        +'<p>One fine body&hellip;</p>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<div class="modal-footer">'
        +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'
        +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>'
        +'</div>'
        +'</div>'
        +'</div>'
        +'</div>';
        document.body.appendChild(modal);
```

And I get the error:

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The
>   new child element is null.

If I put the same HTML inside my index.html it works just fine. What's the problem here?

Comment: A string is not a node. -- "Adds a **node** to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node" -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modal is not an element. It is just a string. `appendChild` expects an actual element reference, not just a string.

**While I don't suggest it**, you could do

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML+modal;
```

This is lame and will remove your event listeners from anything in the body.

You could also do something like:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = modal;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/aCejesa/1/edit)**

If I had that amount of markup in string form, I would just put it in an html file and either include it from the server or load it with javascript via ajax.

You could also create the whole structure using `document.createElement` for each piece.

Comment: @DatProgram it also looks like you're missing a space after "id" and before "tabindex"